# Relationship between CVSS and Risk Level in Nessus output data

Tags: risk, nessus, cvss

In a Nessus output file, does the Risk Level (e.g. Critical, High, Medium, Low, None) depend on the CVSS score? What relationship, if any, do the Risk Level and CVSS have?

Thank yo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

generally Nessus severity ratings will line up to the brackets outlined [here](http://nvd.nist.gov/cvss.cfm) for CVSS Score --> severity mappping so

> NVD Vulnerability Severity Ratings
>   NVD provides severity rankings of "Low," "Medium," and "High" in addition to the numeric CVSS scores
>   but these qualitative rankings are simply mapped from the numeric CVSS base scores:
>
> 1. Vulnerabilities are labeled "Low" severity if they have a CVSS base score of 0.0-3.9.
> 2. Vulnerabilities will be labeled "Medium" severity if they have a base CVSS score of 4.0-6.9.
> 3. Vulnerabilities will be labeled "High" severity if they have a CVSS base score of 7.0-10.0.

However on top of that Nessus has a "critical" rating which according to [this blog post](http://www.tenable.com/blog/cvss-version-2-scoring-with-nessus-and-the-passive-vulnerability-scanner) they use for CVSS 10 vulnerabilities

Comment: Given this information, are the CVE code and the CVSS score also dependent?

Comment: AFAIK CVE codes are just handed out sequentially without specific regard to the severity of the issue.

Comment: Correct, CVE IDs are assigned sequentially